# Ionic: first time input field focus keyboards hides right after coming up only on IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

Hello fellow programmers,

I've been working on an app for a while now and I've been experiencing a problem with the keyboard. When I tab on an input field for the first time the keyboard shows up, but hides afterwards. This happens in a short time. When I tab the input field the second time it works normally.

I have no clue what the problem could be. I've installed the ionic-keyboard plugin and I thought the problem could be related with that plugin. So I've uninstalled it and re-installed it, but my problem wasn't solved.

Any of you had a similar problem?

If so, please let me know!

I would be grateful if someone could give me the solution or at least point me into the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by un-installing the ionic-plugin-keyboard. This plugin was causing the problem for iOS keyboard to glitch. After I de-activated it, the keyboard worked smoothly.